# Differential Calculus - Marginal Revenue at equilibrium price

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Here is the question summed up:

> Demand (sales) for a certain type of product is found to be
>
> $D(p) = 400 - 60p$
>
> at the unit price $p$.
>
> Suppliers are willing to produce
>
> $S(p) = 10p^2$
>
> a) Find equilibrium price
>
> b) find $\frac{dR}{dp}$ (marginal revenue w.r.t. price) at equilibrium
>   price

**What i have tried**

I have done part (a), where we need to solve $D(p) = S(p)$ and solved it with the outcome:

$10(p - 4)(p + 10) = 0$

which gives us the equilibrium price of $p = 4$,  as the price cannot be $-10$.

please help with part (b).

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. I've edited your post adding TeX and improved the formatting. Here is a good tutorial on how to format your questions: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12660/how-to-do-formatting

Comment: Please be more specific: What is your problem with pard (b)? Finding $R$ or differentiating it?

Answer (score 0):

Your revenue is the total income and is the product of the price and the sales 
(demand),

$$ R = D(p)S(p) = (400 - 60p)p = 400p - 60p^2$$ Thus the marginal revenue $\frac{dR}{dp}$ is given by differentiating the above expression

$$ \frac{dR}{dp} = 400-120p = 400-480 = -80 $$
On substituting the value $p=4$.

Comment: Just one thing, the "S(p)" function is the Supply function,  How much the supplier can produce in one week, not sales, sorry I did not make that clear.

Comment: from your answer, I assume the function would be $ R = p(400 - 60p) = 400p - 60p^2$

to differentiate it:

$dR/dp = 400 - 120p = 400 - 480 = -80$

Comment: @CraigFowley I see, I've edited the answer to account for that.